# Const ref versus const pointer as a data member for operator= overloading

Tags: c++

A class with a 'const int&' data member causes the following compilation error when overloading operator= (compiler is g++):

assignment of read-only location.

When the data member is changed to 'const int*', it is fine.

Why?

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
class B {
 private:
  const int& ir;
  //const int* ir;

 public:
  B(const int& i) : ir(i) {}
  //B(const int& i) : ir(&i) {}
  B& operator=(B& b) { ir = b.ir; return *this; }
};
```

g++ error message:

```
opertostack.cpp:9:31: error: assignment of read-only location ‘((B*)this)->       B::ir’
        B& operator=(B& b) { ir = b.ir; return *this; }
                               ^~
```

Comment: Do you know the difference between a pointer and reference?

Comment: You can't assign to a const reference. And you almost certainly don't want to have references as member variables (const or otherwise) anyway.

Comment: 'ir' can be reassigned normally.  It is a const &.  Am I missing something?

Comment: I'm not really used to creating classes like this but isn't he trying to assign a variable to a constant?

Comment: @Jack It can't "be  reassigned normally" - that's what the error message is telling you.

Comment: I use const ref for the clarity of relationship.  If the creation of a class depends on an object of another class, a reference should be made to the latter.  It is like a signature.

Comment: @Jack no it cannot, that's what 'const' means. please re-read c++ basic tutorials

Comment: "I use const ref for the clarity of relationship." using references as class member variables makes the  relationship completely unclear, and maybe impossible, as you have found out. If you want to refer to another object (that is not contained in the class) you almost certainly want some kind of pointer.

Comment: OK.  Neil Butterworth is right.  A const reference can only be initialized once.  Thanks!

Comment: All variables "can only be initialised once" - you need to get clear the difference between initialisation and assignment - it's quite crucial in C++.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot rebind references. Once they are created, they need to refer to the same object for their entire lifetime.

However, your code has much bigger issues. Let's just remove `operator=()` so it compiles. We then instantiate a `B`:

```
B b(42);
```

`b.ir` was bound to the temporary `int` passed to the constructor. That temporary doesn't exists anymore after the constructor returns. `b.ir` is now a dangling reference. It refers to an object that does not exist anymore.

A pointer isn't going to help you either. If we change `B::ir` to be a `const int*` and switch the commented out code, then the result of instantiating a `B` as above is now a dangling pointer. It points to a temporary that doesn't exist anymore.

So in both cases, you get undefined behavior when using `B::ir`.

What you want here is just a normal `int` member. The constructor parameter doesn't need to be a reference either in this case. An `int` is just as easy to copy as a reference so you don't gain anything by using a reference parameter. Finally, the assignment operator should take a `const` reference, so that you can assign from `const B` objects as well:

```
class B {
private:
    int ir;

public:
    B(const int& i) : ir(i) {}
    B& operator=(const B& b) { ir = b.ir; return *this; }
};
```